# activities/fragments' lifecycle methods called in the main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Are all activities/framgents' lifecycle methods called in the main thread by default?
I'm implementing a class which checkes if the app is currently in foreground/background. I'm using activities' onPasue/onResume to do that. I would like to make sure that I don't have to synchronize methods of my class.

Comment: I hope you did have a look at [registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) since this probably makes things easier than using activity and fragment lifecycle methods.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak +1 for mentioning about Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks but I'm developing API 10+

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are.  In general, if something is called off the main thread the documentation will state so.